# Alinhar o topo de divs (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Olá tenho uma pagina onde seus blocos(borda azul e vermelho)(de tamanho diferente) ficam com o topo desnivelado, como poderia resolver este problema?

Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código HTML respectivo:

```
<div class="row">
                <div id="conteudo" class="col-md-12 span7 text-center"><!-- START Video Content -->
                    <div class="star_block" style="border:2px solid blue">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="../../images/temp/13.jpg"
                            alt="Video"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description_block col-md-8" style="border:2px solid red;float:none">
                        <span class="name">info</span><span class="country">value</span><br />
                        <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
                        <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
                        <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
                        <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
                        <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Css aplicado:

```
.star_block{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
.dscription_block{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Testei esse código no Fiddle e não ficou como na figura. Veja aí: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parceiro, se você estiver usando o bootstrap, você dificilmente precisará escrever alguma coisa em CSS, a menos que queira alterar cor e fonte. Questões de alinhamento, margens e etc... o nosso amigo faz tudo pra nós! =)

tente o seguinte:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #000;">
        <!--BORDA PRETA-->
        <h1>CABEÇALHO</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #00F">
            <!--BORDA AZUL-->
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../../images/temp/13.jpg"
                alt="Video"/>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="border:1px solid #f00">
            <span class="name">info</span><span class="country">value</span><br />
            <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
            <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
            <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
            <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
            <span class="info">info</span><span class="value">value</span><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Se quiser que o conteúdo ocupe toda a tela, basta tirar a primeira DIV (container).
Se quando você tirar a div container, aparecer barra de rolagem inferior, basta trocar as classes row por row-fluid

Espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: ,@thomasLima no código que postei havia col-md-4" para <a href="#" class="thumbnail"> pois a imagem poderia ter tamanho variavel

Comment: Ricardo, no seu código não encontrei o col-md-4! Note que no código que postei, fiz justamente isso, ele tem um col-md-4. Além disso, você ainda pode usar a classe img-responsive na tag img, isso também faz a imagem se ajustar a tela

Comment: Desculpe escrevi errado, seria não havia col-md-4" para <a href="#" class="thumbnail"> pois a imagem poderia ter tamanho variavel

Comment: Tudo que tiver dentro da col-md-4, vai se ajustar ao tamanho da div. Exemplo: se você colocar uma imagem com 1920x1080px, ela vai se ajustar ao tamanho daquela div. Ou seja, não importa o tamanho da sua imagem, ela vai se ajustar na div. Se quiser deixar maior ou menor, basta alterar o número de colunas: col-md-3, col-md-5. Só lembrando que se você aumentar ou diminuir essa div, você precisa alterar a div da direita para que ambas fechem em 12.

Comment: Este é o problema o tamanho da imagem não pode ser alterado logo ela não tinha um col-md, e a div a direita sim e um float none para ela permanecer a direita pois se nao tive-se ela tomaria o lugar da primeira ficando na esquerda

Comment: Ok, então se houver imagens maior do que a div, o que deve acontecer? a div se ajustar, ou ficar parte da imagem escondida?

Comment: irá empurrar a div em vermelhor para a direita, se estabelecer um col-md irá redimensionar a imagem se esta for grande

Comment: Nesse caso, você não poderia colocar a imagem e o texto dentro da mesma div, colocando um align='left' na imagem? Já que as divs serão proporcionais ao conteúdo. Não sei qual o seu objetivo, mas se for criar uma lista de videos, um embaixo do outro, com thumbnail na esquerda e descrição na direita, não seria mais interessante você padronizar os tamanhos das 2 colunas, para que o conteúdo fique alinhado?

Comment: Adicionei um pull-left no star_block, e deixo no formato que queria